Attribute error "module 'keras.api.backend' has no attribute 'sigmoid' " while running the code
AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling Activation.call().

module 'keras.api.backend' has no attribute 'sigmoid'

Above error encountered while running the code. Using tensor flow version 2.15 and keras 3.3. No sigmoid function used. still getting error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi @cb ece , The error you're facing indicates a problem with how activations are managed within your Keras model. Despite not directly employing the sigmoid activation function in your code, it appears that at some point in your model, Keras is trying to invoke the sigmoid function, which isn't present in the keras.api.backend module.Review your model architecture to see if you're inadvertently using the sigmoid activation function.f you're preprocessing your data using any Keras functions or utilities, ensure that they are not inadvertently applying sigmoid activation.
